# Sending the same notification for multiple times in GCM Push Notifications

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, push-notification

I am implement the GCM push notification. I have added the registration id for the device in database along with invalid registration id. I am sending auto-generated message from my server to GCM, each message is unique. The problem is I am just getting same notification for 3 or 4 times from GCM. This is due to invalid registration id ?

Comment: can you post your push notification code ?

Comment: @Dynamo yeah i rectify my mistake. Thanks

Comment: @RED.Skull I'm seeing the same issue What exactly did you fix?

Comment: @singhspk Sorry i forgot what i did

Comment: @RED.Skull, Can you able to share the fix...?I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @Jeba same i forgot it

Comment: @RED.Skull, Now it working fine for me. When i am trying to send push notification my regid registered two more times in db. So that only it send twice the notification. Thank you.