# Android GCM send push notification multiple times

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, gcmlistenerservice

I have a released application which is working fine. But now I would like to release a new version and I tested push notification before I upload it to the play store.
In the app I register to GCM and the pushnotification id will be send to our backend. When the user do something in the app or website the backend send a notification to the GCM and the GCM should send the notificaton to users device.
BUT, the device got multiple times this notification.
I logged my GcmListenerService and I see that the onMessageReceived() method called after 2 minutes, and after 4 minutes and after 8 minutes and after 16 minutes, and after 32 minutes. So my application got the same notification multiple times.
Why?

Answer (score 0):

Without further info I would suspect your server is resending the messages rather than the app receiving them multiple times.

Comment: I thought this too, but in the network log I see that the server sent only once the notification. But is it possible that the android app someway call the GcmListenerService? As I know this is not possible

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23080758/5832311), there are instances wherein the GCM engine might change the registration ID whenever it determines it need to. And this might happen at anytime without prior warning. That's why you should always check if the last registration ID matches the one that is current. You may also refer with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094509/sending-the-same-notification-for-multiple-times-in-gcm-push-notifications). Maybe your  regid registered more times in your database.

Comment: I use Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID as my unique deviceId and this is not a good solution for this, right? The problem is that I built my app with assembleRelease and assembleDebug and my deviceId was changed because of my different build types, so I registered more deviceIds to the GCM for one device, right? How can I delete this "wrong" device from GCM? Is it possible?